# Change Nivo Slideshow with thumbnails

Tags: slider, gallery, thumbnails, nivo-slider

I'm trying to do something a little different with Nivo Slider and thumbnails.  Rather than using a thumbnail to jump to a particular slide, I want to use thumbnails to change all of the images in the slideshow completely.  Let me try to explain.  At the top of the page I have the Nivo slider.  Underneath it are 3 thumbnails, we'll call them "thumb1.jpg", "thumb2.jpg", and "thumb3.jpg."

When I click on thumb1.jpg, the slideshow should loop through images 1a.jpg, 1b.jpg, 1c.jpg, etc.  When I click on thumb2.jpg, the slideshow should loop through images 2a.jpg, 2b.jpg, 2c.jpg, etc. When I click on thumb3.jpg, the slideshow should loop through images 3a.jpg, 3b.jpg, 3c.jpg, etc.

All of this needs to happen on one page with one slideshow, rather than having 3 separate pages with 3 separate slideshows.  The solution can use jQuery, PHP, or whatever else works.  Is there any way to accomplish this?

I'm sorry if this has been asked before, but all my searches just came up with using thumbnails to jump to a particular slide. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh...I figured it out with some pretty easy PHP.  The thumbnails are links with a query string, which is used to dictate which directory the pictures get pulled out of.  For example either red/pic1.jpg, red/pic2.jpg or green/pic1.jpg, green/pic2.jpg, or blue/pic1.jpg, blue/pic2.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

You could put them in the css of those small slide indicators I think, I am not very fammiliar with it though, but you could give it a try.

So replace the balls for the images and edit the CSS of it

Comment: Clicking on the balls just makes the slideshow jump from one slide to another.  I want to completely change the images displayed in the slideshow when a thumbnail is clicked.  I don't think your solution would work, but thanks for the suggestion anyway :)